# How to trigger google form add-on to sync using google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms, add-on

New to script here.
Is it possible to use google script to trigger a form add-on to sync?

Objective:
Use script to

- update form data from sheet
- get form to sync with add-on after updated

I only manage to find doc on how to create add-on but not ways to trigger using script.

Problem:
After form updated,
I need to physically click the update button from add-on to sync whenever I amend my form

step I doing now:
[image: open add-on]
[image: Click on more option]
[image: Click on update button]

Trying to achieve:
Get the add-on to auto sync using script to replace the step (the script is the part where I need help) then add time trigger

Any advice or direction will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

I only manage to find doc on how to build add-on but not how to use script to trigger add-on.

after setting up form update data from sheets trigger by time-driven then I not sure how to work on the next step to get the form add-on to sync.

```
    function updateForm(){
    var form = FormApp.openById("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    var drop1 = form.getItemById("xxxxxxxxx").asListItem();
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var names = ss.getSheetByName("xxxxxxxx");
    var drop1Values = names.getRange(2, 1, names.getMaxRows() - 1).getValues();
 
    var name1 = [];
 
    for(var i = 0; i < drop1Values.length; i++)   
    if(drop1Values[i][0] != "")
    name1[i] = drop1Values[i][0];
    drop1.setChoiceValues(name1);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can proceed as follows

In your spreadsheet, put the question title in row 1 and the values ​​above

[image]

Then, with this script you will be able to update your form

```
const form = FormApp.openById('______your_form_ID______');

function updateForm() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1'); // here the Sheet where are located the values
  var title = sh.getRange(1, 1).getValue()
  var values = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1, 1).getValues().flat().filter(v => v != '');
  Logger.log(values)
  var items = form.getItems();
  items.forEach(function (item) {
    if (item.getTitle() == title) {
      var type = item.getType()
      if (type == "MULTIPLE_CHOICE") { item.asMultipleChoiceItem().setChoiceValues(values) }
      else if (type == "LIST") { item.asListItem().setChoiceValues(values) }
      else if (type == "CHECKBOX") { item.asCheckboxItem().setChoiceValues(values) }
    }
  })
}
```

Run the script as needed, even triggering it every time a value has changed

[image]

Comment: Cool, Thanks for the upgrade version for my sheet to update the form.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the upgraded version but the question is after the form is being updated, how to replace the physical work with script that I need to go to the form and click on the add-on to allow the form to sync with the add-on. (refer to image step, (I want to use script to replace the physical work, how can I modify the script to achieve that)

Comment: I apologize, I can't answer to your question since I don't use any  add-on to sync. When I update the form, I use it as is.